# How do I make this code work without JSX?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx

So I have the following JSX code which renders correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First React App</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='app'></div>

    <script type='text/babel'>
        function Avatar(props) {
          return <img src={props.src} />
        }

        function Label(props) {
          return <h1>Name: {props.name}</h1>
        }

        function ScreenName(props) {
          return <h3>username: {props.username}</h3>
        }

        function Badge(props) {
          const user = props.user
          
          return (
            <div>
              <Avatar src={user.img} />
              <Label name={user.name} />
              <ScreenName username={user.username} />
            </div>
          )
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
          <Badge user={{
            name: 'Tyler McGinnis',
            img: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/2933430?v=3&s=460',
            username: 'tylermcginnis'
          }} />,
          document.getElementById('app')
        )
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I attempted to make the above code work without JSX using React.createElement() as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First React App</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='app'></div>

    <script type='text/babel'>
    
        function Avatar(props) {
          return React.createElement(
            'img',
            {src: props.src}
          );
        }

        function Label(props) {
          return React.createElement(
            "h1",
            null,
            "Name: ",
            props.name
          );
        }

        function ScreenName(props) {
          return React.createElement(
            "h3",
            null,
            "username: ",
            props.username
          );
        }

        function Badge(props) {
          const user = props.user;
          
          return React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement(
              Avatar,
              {src: user.img}
            ),
            React.createElement(
              Label,
              {name: user.name}
            ),
            React.createElement(
              ScreenName,
              {username: user.username}
            )
          );
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
          React.createElement(
            Badge,
            {
              User:
              {
                name: 'Tyler McGinnis',
                img: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/2933430?v=3&s=460',
                username: 'tylermcginnis'
              }
            }
          ),
          document.getElementById('app')
        )
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error (please click the link to view the screenshot):
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWrND.png)

Here is another example of my attempt using codepen.io: https://codepen.io/eugenetedkim/pen/eYJrWaZ?editors=1010

I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined

I tried using the online [Babel transcompiler](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQQG4EMroE4AoAO2c-AzgJSIDeAUIotgKZQjZIA8MAtgOaInYQAvJULESAOn4QAvogD0APmrTq1UJFgJEAGXQAjBgBsCRUhRp1GzVojYALAIwKAcuk4MAXFVGlxYNwzSbHKOSipq4NDwSADKEIwMYK7uJmLmtPRMLOx2AMwKICQMrAFeIqYShcX-7kEh-cqq6lFaAELoACbcDKlmVBkQCCRQiFXYiIKIPpVF2BkZVtmIuBl0bB0wqEp0O7ZomDh8AsJj4lzcsoqrO2y6BoaINQwns34Bl9u7tnEJSQGjsyeL2K4jGTw-12CGy2GTIjWoACUGOhoAARADyAFlxIwwB1iis1u0ugwAcVhBYdk8vAByAAqAE9DMVEJiIABxGBgMAwEg0gA013OtLsUCgpA8cjk6AwWGwJAADOJuDAoHYQHoxoMwFBElBxINOHIQHIAEwATlyuQALLkFQB-VCCXIAMhIgmtADYFQLrmDSogaVAmcVOBAVdzeTSMtIPoK6B04BAQO4dcqmABRZmpqCtBkASQ6uBp6Hw-BpcLIQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.4&externalPlugins=) and I couldn't get it to work either.

Please provide any feedback.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the prop User and trying to use as user so the problem is a typo, in the codepen you are getting the ReactDom not defined because you don't include react and react-dom as dependencies in it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really needed a second-hand look. I can't believe I didn't catch that typo and thank you for pointing out the the includes. I appreciate you!